# How to fix the order of floated child div on second row when parent div is resized

Tags: css

Sorry for the title, I can't think of a good way to describe this.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od9g7npt/2/

I have a parent div with 4 child divs, 1 floated left (b) and 3 floated right (c, d, e)

When I make the parent div smaller, first div e goes to second line, below c.

Then as the parent div gets smaller, div d also goes to second line, however it switched place with e, so d is below c instead of e.

Is it possible to make it so that as the parent gets smaller, either d or e always is below c, and they don't switch place?

Also, is it possible to make d (or e) float to the left instead of right when both d and e are on second row (so that d or e is immediately below b)?

```css
#a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
}

#b {
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
}

#c {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#d {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#e {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">div b</div>
  <div id="c">div c</div>
  <div id="d">div d</div>
  <div id="e">div e</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: width are always fixed and the same?

Comment: Yes the child divs' widths are fixed

Comment: so why not considering media query to adjust this?

Comment: How can I use media query to target the parent div? I'm not familiar with it. It's the parent div's width that will change, not the browser size or screen resolution.

Comment: what about this: https://jsfiddle.net/57zLapxb/ ?

Comment: Is it possible to make div c always on top, so that it's always at that top right corner? Also the media query doesn't work for my use case where e.g. parent div's width is 400px but the viewport's width is still wide enough.